# RMM not working when clients send email directly to MC email address - client emails are going into a black hole

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have dynamic sender profiles so clients get communication coming directly from their sales rep. When clients reply to the emails they get the responses directly to their inboxes. This is great.

However, we have an issue where clients are saving/copying the MC email address and creating NEW emails and sending directly to the MC email address '@e.companyname.com.au'. When clients do this - the email goes into a black hole, it does not bounce back to the client, the sales rep and company are not notified and there is no way to access the emails. RMM cant do anything with it.

Surely this is an issue all MC clients are facing - has anyone solved it? Premier Support has been no help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that emails are not coming (or appearing to come) from the actual sales rep - they will be coming from the sales rep's name and address using the SAP subdomain that you have set up. In that sense RMM is functioning exactly as expected...it's designed for reply mail management, not direct mail processing.

If this is something you feel you need to fix, one way would be to purchase an extra private domain from Salesforce that you can use to set up authentication on your base domain. This will allow you to send emails from Marketing Cloud that are fully authenticated and now come from the sales reps real email address. So rather than emails appearing to come from samsample@e.companyname.com.au, they will actually come from samsample@companyname.com.au. If someone decides to pick up that email address and send to it, the email goes direct to the sales rep without touching Marketing Cloud.

Just keep in mind if you do go that way you'll want to do custom RMM settings for your dynamic sender profile so replies go direct to the sales rep rather than back through SFMC. So you lose the ability to do auto-filtering etc

Comment: Thanks, Jarret! 
Last night I set up our base domain as a Registered Domain in the 'From Address Management' section in Set up. 

I have also tested just adding our sales reps as Verified email addresses in the 'From Address Management' Section as well. I have done some test emails and it all seems to work perfectly....

Do you know of any downside to doing this?  Now I am not sure why we need the MC specific subdomains at all? Do you know?

Comment: You have an MC specific subdomain for your Sender Authentication Package...Salesforce creates subdomains of that and they run things like the domain your images are stored on, click tracking, reply mail management etc. Unless you've specifically asked for and installed authentication on your base domain it shouldn't actually exist.

Comment: The fact you can verify an address implies maybe you do, but it might pay to send an email from Marketing Cloud using an email address from the base domain to the email address you can get from https://www.mail-tester.com/. This will tell you if there's any issues with authentication on the domain you're sending from.